# I want to change the size of the locationbutton swiftUI

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, location, core-location

```
import CoreLocationUI  
LocationButton(.currentLocation, action: {
                        
            }).labelStyle(.iconOnly)
```

I didn't find helpful documentation for the new location button. please if there is any way to change the size of the button help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Apple restricts the modification of this special button:

> Consider customizing the location button to harmonize with your UI.
> Specifically, you can:
>
> - Choose the system-provided title that works best with your feature,
>   such as “Current Location” or “Share My Current Location”
> - Choose the filled or outlined location glyph
> - Select a background color and a
>   color for the title and glyph
> - Adjust the button’s corner radius
>
> To help people recognize and trust location buttons, **other visual
> attributes aren't customizable**.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/accessing-user-data/

Answer (score 0):

After going through the documentation again I figured out something that can help to make the button a little more bigger:

```
CoreLocationUI  
LocationButton(.currentLocation, action: {} )
              .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
              .font(.largeTitle)
```

For more details you can view this documentation
https://sarunw.com/posts/location-button/#customization